# Write a JavaScript conditional statement to find the sign of product of three numbers. Display an alert box with the specified sign

Tags: javascript, html

I want to write a JavaScript conditional statement to find the sign of product of three numbers. Display an alert box with the specified sign. The three numbers have to be written in input fields. And when I click on an OK button, it should tell me what sign of product I have. Is it a postive number(+) or negative(-)?

```
<body>
Please enter numbers that aren't 0.
<input id="x" type="text" name="" value="">
<input id="y" type="text" name="" value="">
<input id="z" type="text" name="" value="">
<button type="onclick" onclick="value()" name="button">OK</button>

<script>
 function value() {
 document.getElementById('x').innerHTML;
 document.getElementById('y').innerHTML;
 document.getElementById('z').innerHTML;

 if (x>0 && y>0 && z>0)
 {
      alert("The sign is +");
 }
 else if (x<0 && y<0 && z<0)
       {
         alert("The sign is +");
       }
       else if (x>0 && y<0 && z<0)
       {
         alert("The sign is +");
       }
       else if (x<0 && y>0 && z<0)
       {
         alert("The sign is +");
       }
       else
       {
         alert("The sign is -");
       }
  }
    </script>
      </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Okay... what exactly is your question?

Comment: inputs do not have `innerHTML`, they have `value`. You do nothing with `document.getElementById('x').innerHTML;` x is an object, not a value. `console.log(x);`

Comment: why not take the product first and then check the sign?

Comment: `if (x<0 && y<0 && z<0)` shouldn't that be negative?

Comment: The issue is that inputs return a string and you want a number, so select the inputs, get their value and parse that value. In the original excercise solution on w3resource, x y and z were already variables.

Comment: This sounds like copy+pasted homework. You didnt even bother to reword it. If you cant put effort into wanting to learn we cant put effort into teaching you.

Comment: When you'll be done listing all differents possibilities in your `if/else if` to get the sign. Add 3 more inputs and fix your function to make sure all 6 fields are taken in account. When you are done with all possibilities, add 10 inputs. When you'll notice it's impossible to hand-write all possibilities, stop coding and think about what you can do to fix that

Comment: @Shilly JS does an implicit conversion. Open dev console and type `"-1" < 0`

Comment: @Cid Never trust implicit coercion in JS, results are sometimes odd, and the rules are hard to learn.

Comment: @Cid That's not true for inputs with the type text. Since they are both strings, no automatic conversion. `<input type="text" id="first" value="10"></input><input type="text" id="second" value="20"></input><script>alert( document.querySelector( '#first' ).value + document.querySelector( '#second' ).value );</script>` gives you 1020 instead of 30.

Comment: @Shilly yeah, using `+` will often (always?) lead to erroneous result. All he needs is to multiply all 3 numbers. The problem isn't about converting string to int, altough it's a good practice that should be done all the time. There is more to fix before pointing that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Input elements have a `value` not, `innerHTML`
2. Even if you would have corrected that, you will not have values, since you did not assign them to any variable
3. For number only `input` use the `number` type, this will prevent someone from entering not numeral characters (in all modern browsers)

```js
document.getElementById('check-value').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const x = document.getElementById('x').value;
  const y = document.getElementById('y').value;
  const z = document.getElementById('z').value;
  if (x + y + z >= 0) {
    alert("The sign is +");
  } else if (x < 0 && y < 0 && z < 0) {
    alert("The sign is +");
  } else if (x > 0 && y < 0 && z < 0) {
    alert("The sign is +");
  } else if (x < 0 && y > 0 && z < 0) {
    alert("The sign is +");
  } else {
    alert("The sign is -");
  }
});
```

```html
Please enter numbers that aren't 0.<br>
<input id="x" type="number" name="" value="">
<input id="y" type="number" name="" value="">
<input id="z" type="number" name="" value="">
<button type="button" id="check-value" name="button">OK</button>
```

Comment: When you'll be done listing all differents possibilities in your if/else if to get the sign. Add 3 more inputs and fix your function to make sure all 6 fields are taken in account. When you are done with all possibilities, add 10 inputs. When you'll notice it's impossible to hand-write all possibilities, stop coding and think about what you can do to fix that.

Comment: "Giving a man a fish feeds him for a day, teaching a man to fish fees him for life." You arent helping the OP by giving them a code solution without explaining the how or why

Comment: @Cid & @Marie I agree with both, but considering the low quality of the question, anything more advanced then what they are currently doing, will create more confusion on their side. i even regret putting the `addEventListener` in there.

Comment: @Dementic then take your time to write a quality answer, instead of posting poor  code (don't take offense) without any explanation for someone who is clearly a beginner. You have 8k+ reputation, you know how the SO community is.

Comment: @Cid The multiple `IF` statements are checking different `rules`, even though the OP said `Is it a postive number(+) or negative(-)`

Comment: This should check the sign of the *"product of three numbers"*. harrisonbooth gave the best answer so far.

Comment: The if/else mess is actually from the solution provided with the question on w3resources. The OPs issue is that in the original solution, x y and z were already variables. So I don't think Demetic should be blamed for a bad tutorial.

Comment: @Cid the question was not `How can i get rid of the IF statements`, it was about making the code work. harrisonbooth answer is the best answer for `is there a better way to implement this?`

Answer (score 1):

Why not multiply them then set the condition on the product?

```
const x = document.getElementById('x').value;
const y = document.getElementById('y').value;
const z = document.getElementById('z').value;

const product = x*y*z;
let sign = (product < 0) ? '-' : '+';
sign = (product === 0) ? 'Neither' : sign;
alert(sign);
```

Comment: 0 is neither plus nor minus.

Answer (score 0):

You should parse value of input fields using

```
var x = Number("Your input field");
```

Then Your variable will be treated as integer and Your condition of bigger or smaller than 0 will work.