# jQuery sum input values of each divs?

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a way to create a sum of inputs within an element.

I'm running into this problem that whenever I'm using each, the function itself sums all values and not just those within the div.

Working with this isn't working as hoped:

```
$('div').each(function(){
    var sum = 0;

    $(this).find('input').each(function(){
        sum += Number($(this).val());
        });

        $('.sum').val(sum);

});
```

home someone can help:

http://jsfiddle.net/1keyup/q7rL2a38

Comment: @Dementic uhm... wut? the op isn't getting the value of a div.

Comment: and this question is very similar to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54239232/write-a-javascript-conditional-statement-to-find-the-sign-of-product-of-three-nu/54239436#54239436

Comment: This is a duplicate, but not of that question. It's a duplicate of one of the dozen of other cases of using `$('.classname')` instead of `$('.classname', this)`

Comment: @KevinB My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `$('.sum').val(sum);` you'll set a value for all the `.sum` inputs .. So you just need to refer to the `.sum` input within each `div` you can do this by use  `$(this).find('.sum').val(sum);`

```js
$('div').each(function(){
  var sum = 0;
  
  $(this).find('input').each(function(){
    sum += Number($(this).val());
  });
  
  $(this).find('.sum').val(sum);
  
});
```

```css
div{
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 7px
}

input{ padding: 3px 5px; font-family: monospace; width: 50px}
div:first-child{
  border: 1px solid grey;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
div:nth-child(2){
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1);
}
div:nth-child(3){
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="text" class="tosum" value="1"/> +
  <input type="text" class="tosum" value="1"/> = 
  <input type="text" class="sum"/>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" class="tosum" value="2"/> +
  <input type="text" class="tosum" value="5"/> = 
  <input type="text" class="sum"/>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" class="tosum" value="3"/> +
  <input type="text" class="tosum" value="3"/> = 
  <input type="text" class="sum"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Mohamed-Yousef, thanks a lot, it's working :)

Comment: I'm glad it helped .. you're welcome @daniel .. Have a great day :-)